# How do I properly attach this 3.2 inch LCD to a raspberry pi zero w

Tags: display

I purchased a 3.2 inch LCD screen from souq.com as that's pelretty much all I have to get a display for the raspberry pi zero w.

The issue is, when I attach the board to the pi, all I get is a white screen (backlight).

After doing some digging, I thought it was a waveshare tft. Upon further investigation it is not. It's a possible knock-off clone perhaps?

Any always: the vendor package says it's an ILI9341 board.

I am using Raspian on the Pi Zero-W (latest version).

However, the display is only white light. The vendor did not include ANY documents to tell me anything about this display.

I am attaching pictures.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi stackexchange. 
We would need some kind of reference, datasheet maybe, or link.

Comment: This might be useful [link](https://github.com/juj/fbcp-ili9341/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: @smajli a datasheet was not given by the vendor

Comment: @RaviMaliravi I will check it out

Answer (score 1):

I bought once a similar screen, on Amazon (Quimat). The instructions were to clone this github repo : https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show

The display output goes to i2c interface in replacement to the standard HDMI. You need a dtb overlay driver you can find on that site.

There is a script that add that overlay file (a .dtb file) on the boot partition, and modify the cmdline.txt and config.txt file so the kernel knows where to output the display. And then add parameters to X11 for the graphic interface.

Instructions are in the readme file of the repo :

```
1/ Install a fresh Raspbian copy on the SD
2/ ssh on your Rpi and clone the repo : 
    git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git
3/ according to your display type, execute the script ( sudo ./LCD32-show from the LCD-show directory for the 3.2" )
```

To switch back to the HDMI output : run ./LCD-hdmi (which remove i2c connectivity